# how to set color of Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How can I set the color of a JButton ?

I have tried this:

```
button.setBackground(Color.red);
```

but with no success. This just changes the color of button's border.
I then tried to override `paintComponents`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
}
```

but now I don't see the text on the JButton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to color your buttons is to use ImageIcons instead of text.
You could use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) in order to design them.

Make sure that the **background is transparent**!

```
button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/myimage.png")));
```

This is a disabled `button.setDisabledIcon(...` button:

[image]

This is an enabled button, not pressed:

[image]

This is a pressed enabled button:

[image]

The background color-change after pressing is done by Swing. You need just 2 images for this.

Comment: yea I try this too but when I use icon to whole button then there is no graphic action (some change of color) when button is pressed.

Comment: The little trick here is that you should make the background of the image transparent.

Comment: +1 but I don't know what Gimp has to do with it.  You can produce a solid color image at run-time in around 5 lines of code.

Comment: I just make my png's with Gimp. :-)

Answer (score 3):

What the background color affects depends on your look and feel. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html

You should choose a look and feel that uses the background color the way you want. I don't know what you are using at the moment. If you have the default LAF setting the color and removing the border should be enough:

```
button.setBackground(color);
button.setBorder(null);
```